# how to make typing two objects in an array or the whole array?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I did the typing using TypeScript, it works correctly for one object. But when I create two objects I get an error. how to make this code work correctly? maybe that's not how I write typing?

```
export type TestType = [
  {
    id: string;
    fullname: string;
    appId: string;
    status: StatusValue[];
  },
];

export type StatusValue = {
  text: string;
  background: string;
};
```

2

```
import { TestType } from './types';

class Testpage {
  data: TestType = [
    {
      id: '1423',
      fullname: 'Hello world',
      appId: '32112324dsadas123123',
      status: [
        {
          text: 'test',
          background: '#fff',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: '1422',
      fullname: 'Hello world2',
      appId: '32112324dsadas1231233',
      status: [
        {
          text: 'test2',
          background: '#000',
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
}

export default Testpage;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have hardcoded `TestType` to an array with a single object. Instead of this way change `TestType` to look like the following:

```js
export type TestType = {
    id: string;
    fullname: string;
    appId: string;
    status: StatusValue[];
};
```

Now use it like:

```js
class Testpage {
  data: TestType[] = [
    {
      id: '1423',
      fullname: 'Hello world',
      appId: '32112324dsadas123123',
      status: [
        {
          text: 'test',
          background: '#fff',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: '1422',
      fullname: 'Hello world2',
      appId: '32112324dsadas1231233',
      status: [
        {
          text: 'test2',
          background: '#000',
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
}
```